# Hadoop v1.1.2 plug-in for Eclipse v4.3 (kepler) on Ubuntu12.10

Tags: eclipse-plugin, hadoop-plugins

I've downloaded the Hadoop v1.1.2 plugin for Eclipse from [this](https://github.com/itsamiths/hadoop-eclipse-plugins) site and have put it in the Eclipse plugins directory.

The MapReduce view is available but I cannot include any 'org.apache.hadoop' libraries in my code - I get the following error;

> The import org.apache cannot be resolved.

Am I missing something obvious? Are there any known issues with
a) The plugin for Hadoop v1.1.2?
b) Running the plugin with Eclipse v4.3?
c) Running the plugin on an Ubuntu VM?

I've trawled the internet but many of the issues are to do with earlier versions of the plugin and /or Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just importing the packages won't help. You need to add the necessary jars to your project as well. You can do that by following these steps :

**Click on your Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add External JARs**

This will open the selection window. Move to your **HADOOP_HOME** and add the **hadoop-core-1.1.2.jar** and all the required jars from **HADOOP_HOME/lib** folder to your project.

Alternatively, create your project **as a MapReduce Project** instead of **as a Java Project**.

HTH

Comment: Thank you so much!  I feared it was something really basic I was missing, and sure enough...  Thanks again.